# Page-unbreakable centered itemized list

Tags: itemize, minipage, varwidth

I am trying to write new environment that would centre an itemised list, and here is the code for it:

```
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{mitemize}{
     \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}%
         \centering%
         \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}%
             \begin{itemize}[rightmargin=1.3cm]%
             \setlength\itemsep{-0.2em}%
}{
             \end{itemize}%
         \end{varwidth}%
     \end{minipage}%
}
```

And the thing is that, when I am using this environment in my document, and it is a very time for list to break one page to continue on another one, list is completely carried over the new page.

Alas, I do not know why it is happening. Any ideas?

Minimal working example is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{mitemize}{
     \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}%
         \centering%
         \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}%
             \begin{itemize}[rightmargin=1.3cm]%
             \setlength\itemsep{-0.2em}%
}{
             \end{itemize}%
         \end{varwidth}%
     \end{minipage}%
}

\newcommand{\phrase}{Withthelightsoutit'slessdangerousHerewearenow,entertainusI feelstupidandcontagiousHerewearenow,entertainusAmulatto,an AlbinoAmosquito,mylibido,yeah}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\vspace{7pt}
\begin{mitemize}
\item \phrase
\item \phrase
\item \phrase
\item \phrase
\end{mitemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `minipage`s do not break across page boundaries.  They will always cram themselves on a single page.

Comment: So you are happy with your MWE.  Pity, creating a breakable centered itemized list is a much more interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `varwidth` box in a `center` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{mitemize}
 {\begin{center}
  \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}[
    leftmargin=2cm,
    rightmargin=\dimexpr2cm-\labelwidth\relax,
    itemsep=-0.2em]
 }{\end{itemize}
   \end{varwidth}
   \end{center}}

\newcommand{\phrase}{With the lights out it's
  less dangerous Here we are now, entertainus I feel stupid
  andcontagious Here we are now, entertainus A mulatto, an 
  Albino A mosquito, mylibido, yeah}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{mitemize}
\item \phrase
\item \phrase
\item \phrase
\item \phrase
\end{mitemize}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can tcolorboxify an `itemize` environment within a non-linewidth, centered and breakable tcolorbox.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\phrase}{With the lights out it's less dangerous Here we are now, entertain us I feel stupid and contagious Here we are now, entertain us A mulatto, an Albino Amosquito, my libido, yeah}

\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}

\tcolorboxenvironment{myitemize}{%
    blanker,
    center,
    breakable,
    width=.75\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{myitemize}
\item \phrase
\item \phrase
\item \phrase
\item \phrase
\end{myitemize}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]